# Troubleshoot client's CSS issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, browser-cache

I am facing a super weird issue here.

I built a website for my client on my test domain for testing, last week they sent me a email saying they cannot browse this site. From their screenshot I could see their browser (ie10 in win8) is not loading CSS file.

I tested this site on my IE10 in win7 and also tested ie10 in win8 on Browserstack (crossbrowser checking tool). And my collogues also checked on their working PC/MAC. Obviously everything is working fine. I told them to ctrl+F5 to clear the cache so there should be nothing with the cache.

If this is an issue about ie10 I would be happy to troubleshot and modify my CSS but it is an issue with client's specific browser in specific OS so I have totally no idea how to troubleshot that.

Except the Ctrl+F5, is there any other suggestion I could tell my client to solve their problem? Or is there any way I could optimized my CSS file to avoid this?

Comment: Using Firebug or a similar tool, is the CSS file downloading or returning an HTTP error? Has the client tried a different browser on the same machine and/or network?

Comment: Use http://fiddlercap.com to get a capture of the client's traffic, then compare that capture to your local capture.

Comment: @JonAdams: Thank you. There is totally no error on my working PC. Client feel happy with other browsers but they are concern about our website now.